# Maximum number of keyboards you can attach

Tags: usb, keyboard, usb-hub

I need to attach 16 keyboards to a computer, to use as a game show buzzer system. Is that possible? I know the theoretical maximum number of USB devices allowed is (2^7)-1=127 but will there be any additional limitations? I will be using USB hubs, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I would give it a try the only thing is they may draw so much power that you may need to buy the extra USB hubs that you can plug in. Ill try to give you a link to what I'm talking about.

Comment: Powered USB hubs is definitely recommended.